# detect iframe height changes without iframe reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

In my web project, I have an iframe.
It holds one graph, and a table holding values of graph. (graph = google graph api, table=datatables)

Sometimes iframe content height changes by its js applications, not by reloading an html.

So I need to detect those changes originating from js's and increase i-frame size.

How can I detect those changes?

Here is my function that increases i-frame size. (For your reference)

```
  function update_height() {        
            $('#iframe-1').load( function() {
            var $ifbody = $(this).contents().find( 'body' );
            $ifbody.css( 'height','auto' );
            $(this).height( $ifbody.height() );
    }); 
   };
```

Comment: how about setInterval to check the offsetHeight of the content of the iframe and accordingly you change ur height // thats if i got u right ?

Comment: Thanks I will try this, but it is better not to poll for height changes continuously, according to my project constraints.

Comment: if there is a way to catch the function that resize the inner content of the iframe and there u can handel the height of the iframe // i dont know is this possible any way //

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't want to use polling, maybe you should consider firing a custom event from the iframe js. Assuming you are also using jquery in the iframe js, you can add this whenever your iframe content changes:

```
parent.$('#iframe-1').trigger("iframeResize", [$("body").height()]);
```

Then, in the parent page, set your handler for when the event is fired:

```
$('#iframe-1').bind('iframeResize', function(event, newSize) {
    $(this).height(newSize);
    //or whatever else you'd like to do, such as call your update_height() function
});
```

If you don't want to send the `newSize` parameter with the event (or your iframe js does not know it at the time of firing the event), then you can put your `update_height()` code into the `bind()` handler to get the size of the iframe body.

Comment: I tried it but I doesnt seem to be binded and working. so I didnt succeded with this code. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

the page the iframe is within and the page that is provided as the src of the iframe have to be from the same origin (same origin policy). If that is the case, javascript can talk from one page to the other (postMessage or via HashChange) or by directly accessing the windows parents window and resize the iframe.

access the iframe on the main document from within the iframe;

```
function updateHeight(newHeight){
    parent.document.getElementById("iframe").style.height=newHeight+"px";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes they are on the same domain. But problem is I am unable detect changes made by iframe js code. iframe has some js code and it is dynamically updating its content.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using jQuery:

```
$('#iframe-1').load(function(){ 
    $(this).height($(this).contents().find('body').height()); 
});
```

That should do the trick as long as the iframe domain and protocols match, for the initial load.

Then to keep it updated as the height changes...

```
$('#iframe-1').contents().find('body').bind('resize', function(){
    $('#iframe-1').height($(this).height());
});
```

Should do it... probably...

Comment: Sorry but both of them didnt worked for me. iframe doesnt show up on load. (as you know I dont provide height for iframe)